# Question about electric flux in the corner of a cube

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

> A charge $Q$ is places at the corner of a cube of side $a$. What is the electric flux through all the six faces of the cube? What is the electric flux on each one of it's faces?

I am aware of Gauss' Law, but, I don't know how the charge being in the corner of the cube instead of the center of a sphere affects things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ask how many cubes are required to fill the total volume about a point. Eight cubes. Hence the answer should be the total flux through the whole space divided by 8.

Comment: I kind of had that intuition, but, I was not able to formalize the logic. Also, how does the answer to the second part look like?

Comment: For the three faces it would be zero and then equally divided among the three due to the symmetry.

Comment: Why would it be zero for the aligned faces? (I am guessing the 3 aligned faces would have zero)

Comment: The three faces attached to the charge have the flux zero is since cos theta zero. (90 deg between electric field and area vector). The other three are symmetrically placed about the charge